# Platform-independent path (in LaTex and Elisp)?

Tags: emacs, latex, path, cross-platform, elisp

I run Emacs on Win7 and Ubuntu and try to share most of my configuration via dropbox.com. I still could not figure out how to write the path to load-files or images (for example) in a platform independent way.

I mirrored my directory structure on both machines so that inside the home directory the relative path should work out. Is there a way to achieve this with a single path without if-clauses (if system ... else ...) everywhere?

I tried ~/  and it worked sometimes, sometimes not.

'home' is set on Win7, but it must be addressed as %home% on Win7 and as $HOME on ubuntu (right?).

I need a solution for:

- elisp code
- latex files  (adress images, listings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a setting at the top of my .emacs the tests the OS, and sets a CONST pointing to the the root directory of the path accordingly. Then, within the configurations, I just reference the variable within my path statements. Just tested on OS X and Windows 7.

Here's some examples:

```
(defconst HOME_DIR 
  (if (eq system-type 'darwin)
      (concat "/Users/" (getenv "USER"))
    (concat "c:/cygwin/home/" (getenv "USER")))
  "Home directory. I could rely on the HOME environment variable,
  but I'm being retentive.")

(defconst EMACS_PKGS (concat HOME_DIR "/emacs-pkgs")
  "Directory for the emacs pkgs and configuration files.
 Default uses `HOME_DIR' as a prefix")

;; isolate customize settings
(setq custom-file (concat EMACS_PKGS "/emacs-custom.el"))
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I was looking for. Definitely works for elisp, might even work for latex. Thanks.

Comment: After fiddling around with this solution I encountered a few issues. 1. when staring emacs as root for some admin work,the (getenv "USER") causes problems, since the user is root. 2. putting my own directories at front of load-path didn't work any more, since add-to-list apparently inerpreted the list (concat HOMR_DIR "/my-dir/") as 'element' and as an argument for 'append' at the same time, and therefore appended the directories. By giving only a string as 'element', like "~/my-dir/, 'append' was nil again and the dirs put in front.

Comment: @Thorsten I'm not seeing that using this format: `(add-to-list 'my-list (concat EMACS_PKGS "/1")) (add-to-list 'my-list (concat EMACS_PKGS "/2")) (add-to-list 'my-list (concat EMACS_PKGS "/3"))` Also, you can use tramp to load a file as root in a running emacs session with the following format (using /etc/hosts as an example): `C-x C-f /su::/etc/hosts` See [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Emacs#Tips_and_tricks) for details

Answer (score 3):

In Windows, `~` resolves to whatever the HOME environment variable is set to. I found it most useful to set HOME to `C:\Users\username` (in Win 7). This means I can put my .emacs file there, and also that `~` will reference files in it when I'm opening files.

Once you do this, your elisp can refer to `~` as your home directory on either Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with Emacs on Windows is that `~` is not at C:\Users\yourusername. For me, it's in C:\Users\rafe\AppData\Roaming. So, for the case of Emacs, if you drop files in, say, %HOME%\AppData\Roaming (or, in Windows Emacs, `~`), you'll have access to those files. That's where my .emacs was by default, at least. The path might be different on your system, so see where Emacs takes you when you try to find a file and type `~/`.

That setting might be configurable, but I've never cared enough to change it.

As for LaTeX, sadly I can't help.

Comment: Interactively, ~/ brings me to c:/Users/me inside Emacs on my Win7 machine (because I configured the 'home' variable). But using ~/latexProject/myfile inside a .tex file causes an error on the Win7 machine (not in Ubuntu). And I had a problem with ~/ in elisp files too on my Win7 machine (in relation to Symlinks ?), unfortunately I don't remember exactly. Would be nice to have something thats more independent from emacs, like a generic way to address HOME.

Answer (score 0):

For LaTeX, see: [“How to add an extra searchable dir with personal style files to TeXLive, NOT under ~/Library/texmf?”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5162) on the TeX SE.  It might help.

Comment: Looks interesting, there is even a hint for dropbox users. I'll check it out.